# How does HA proxy use bandwidth?

Tags: haproxy, bandwidth, bandwidth-measuring

We're using HA proxy for load balancing web servers. How does bandwidth usage work for HA proxy? HA proxy is on a different network than the web servers. Does the bandwidth that ends up being used come from HA proxy to the client loading the web site, or does HA proxy simply route the connection to the web server directly and the web server uses its own bandwidth?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

As the name states, HAProxy will work as a proxy and for the client, it looks like it speaks only to the HAProxy server, while it transparently forwards the traffic to one of several backend application servers  (which usually aren't accessible from the outside). Thus, you will use the bandwidth between the HAProxy and the backend servers plus about the same amount again between the HAProxy server and the client.

How this model fits in your question you have to know yourself because I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I am basically trying to figure out if my outbound web traffic will be served by HA proxy. Let's say the response of the web pages is 1MB of data total and it goes client -> HA proxy -> web server. The web server responds with 1MB of data. Does that data go directly to the client or does it go web server -> HA proxy -> client? In other words, HA proxy's outbound traffic is the equal to the sum of all the web servers' outbound traffic.

Comment: Your outbound traffic originates from the HAproxy and it about the same amount as the sum of the traffic of all web servers to the HAproxy server, yes. At least that's how I used it, but it might be there are other ways to configure this.

Comment: So if server 1 moves 1Gbps and server 2 also moves 2Gbps. HAproxy server needs at least a 2Gbps port to move that. And server 1 and 2 sill spend whatever bandwidth they send AND HAproxy will spend the sum of server 1 + 2 bandwidth.
If my assumptions are correct, HAproxy isn't cheap.